# How to keep accessory view set when leaving the view then coming back later

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have not attempeted this before so would like people opinion on how best to handle tableviewcell tick accessory, I have set this up so that when the user selects their uitableview cell they are directed back to the main view and the value of the cell selected is loaded into the main view, I have done this using protocols and delegates like [so](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/)

My question is, if the user decides to go back to the view where the accessory is how do I make sure the tick stays their? is their a special method I can use? or will i have to pass the indexpath to the main view then back again using delegates and protocols?

Anyway any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to pass the indexpath to the main view then back again using delegates and protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in your question. You will need to keep a reference with what `indexPath` was selected. And you this value can be saved on to `AppDelegate` or which ever method you may choose. When the user wishes to go back to the view, you will simply need to check for saved values, and load them on to the `UITableView` with `tableView reloadData`.

You will have to set the `accessoryView` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and provide the check for saved values there. You can `reloadData` in the `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: okay great, thanks for that.. the one thing that i didnt think of was using viewwillappear..  thanks for the confirmation.